# How to do a 2nd tier dropdown with html and css

Tags: html, css

I am doing this dropdown menu for my team's websites, and I want to have a dropdown ppear next to it when you hover over a link in the 1st dropdown:

```html
<nav id="menu-Items">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">General</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="General" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Study Tools</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Professors</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Find a Study Buddy</a></li> 
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="Study-Tools" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Patreon</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">SubscribeStar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Paypal</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Stripe</a></li>
                                    <li id="Crypto"><a href="#">Cryptocurrency</a>
                                        <ul id="method">
                                            <li><a href="#">Bitcoin</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ripple</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Bitcoin Cash</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">EOS</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Cardano</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">LiteCoin</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Stellar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">IOTA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">NEO</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <img id="Cryptocurrency" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/Left-arrow.png">
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="Donate" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Spread The Love</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="StL" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Give to Charity</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

and Ive tried some css that I saw in a youtube video:

```css
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    width: 150px;
}

nav ul li ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 170px;
    top: 0px;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

And the second dropdoewn would appear, but when I hover over "Donate" instead of "Cryptocurrency". If anyone could help me, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you actually need to add proper classes on every ul or li to group them together.
So you need to remove the position: absolute cause it changes the position of your certain navigation.

```
nav ul li ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; /* remove this line*/
  right: 170px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Second, you need to tell specifically what element you will need to use display: block when hover. Since you use an ID: "Crypto" in your Cryptocurrency:

```
#Crypto:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

and remove the

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

As this CSS selector will display the hidden block with similar CSS selector

```css
#Crypto:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    width: 150px;
}

nav ul li ul li ul {
    display: none;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    right: 170px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu-Items">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">General</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="General" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Study Tools</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Professors</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Find a Study Buddy</a></li> 
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="Study-Tools" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Patreon</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">SubscribeStar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Paypal</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Stripe</a></li>
                                    <li id="Crypto"><a href="#">Cryptocurrency</a>
                                        <ul id="method">
                                            <li><a href="#">Bitcoin</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ripple</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Bitcoin Cash</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">EOS</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Cardano</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">LiteCoin</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Stellar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ethereum</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">IOTA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">NEO</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <img id="Cryptocurrency" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/Left-arrow.png">
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="Donate" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Spread The Love</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <img id="StL" src="../../../Images/Main/HomePage/Header/down_arrow.png">
                            <li><a href="#">Give to Charity</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```